# How to replace strings in all files using sed?

Tags: sed

I want to replace below line with next line in all the files. So what `sed` pattern is used for this. I have tried lot but not figured that out..

```
checkToken($token['token'])
checkToken($token)
```

This is what I have tried

```
sed -i -- 's/checkToken\(\$token\['token'\]\)/checkToken\(\$token\)/g' get_officers_v2.php
```

Comment: What do you mean by *all files*? Does this command work on a single file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to get your escape-characters (`\`) on the right place like:

```
sed -ie "s/\(checkToken(\$token\)\['token'\])/\1)/" get_officers_v2.php
```